# ASP.NET MVC 3 : How to force an ActionLink to do a HttpPost instead of an HttpGet?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

Is it possible to force an `@Html.ActionLink()` to do a `POST` instead of a `GET`?  If so, how?

Comment: No you can't they are only for GET

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`ActionLink` helper method  will render an `anchor` tag, clicking on which is always a `GET` request. If you want to make it a `POST` request. You should override the default behviour using a little javacsript

```
@ActionLink("Delete","Delete","Item",new {@id=4},new { @class="postLink"})
```

Now some `jQuery` code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function(){
    $("a.postLink").click(function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      $.post($(this).attr("href"),function(data){
          // got the result in data variable. do whatever you want now
          //may be reload the page
      });
    });    
  });    
</script>
```

Make sure you have an `Action` method of `HttpPost` type to handle this request

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Delete(int id)
{
  // do something awesome here and return something      
}
```

Answer (score 8):

I suppose that if you need something like that is for an Action that will be doing something "permanent" on server side. For instance, deleting an object in database.

Here is a complete example of doing a delete using a link and posting:
http://www.squarewidget.com/Delete-Like-a-Rock-Star-with-MVC3-Ajax-and-jQuery

**From the previous link (recomended reading anyway):**

A delete link in your view:

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", "Widget",
                new {id = item.Id},
                new AjaxOptions {
                    HttpMethod = "POST",
                    Confirm = "Are you sure you want to delete this widget?",
                    OnSuccess = "deleteConfirmation"
                })
```

A bit of JS:

```
function deleteConfirmation(response, status, data) {

        // remove the row from the table
        var rowId = "#widget-id-" + response.id;
        $('.widgets').find(rowId).remove();

        // display a status message with highlight
        $('#actionMessage').text(response.message);
        $('#actionMessage').effect("highlight", {}, 3000);
    }
```

Comment: great link.  wish i could mark 2 answers as correct, so hopefully an upvote will suffice.  thanks

Answer (score 4):

What I would do is wrap your html around a form

```
@using(Html.BeginForm("YourAction","YourController", FormMethod.Post)){

<button>Hello</button>

}
```

Instead of using a link you might want to use a button.

If you really want to use a link, you might need some javascript

Something like this:

```
$("#idOfYourLink").click(function(){
var form = $(this).parents('form:first');
form.submit();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to have a `<a>` element perform a POST to a web server.

You can use Javascript to capture the click event, stop the navigation, and perform an AJAX POST to the server, but if the user has Javascript disabled nothing will happen.

Do you have to use a `<a>` element, or just something that *resembles* a `<a>` element?

Also worth mentioning is to have a look at `AjaxLink`. It allows you to easily use a `<a>` element to perform an AJAX POST.

Answer (score 0):

If you think... there is no tag for link in HTML that does a POST. And that's why you can't force a link to do a POST (and it doesn't make any sense).
To use "POST", ou should "POST" something. And that something should be a form, or you can do a POST using a javascript function for AJAX.
Anyway, if you need to POST without post anything you should review your resourcemodel, something stinks.

Comment: This is actually quite common and perfectly acceptable in the Rails community for example as a way to delete objects.